# A gcc error when I was using SDL2 that installed by vcpkg in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, gcc, sdl-2, vcpkg

Lately, I was learning the SDL tutorial on lazyfoo.
I copy the lesson code into main.c, and changed `#include <SDL.h>` into `#include "SDL2/SDL.h"`.
Because I installed SDL2 by vcpkg.
Actually the include path had been add into includePath.

```
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-windows/include",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x86-windows/include"
            ],
```

And then I build and debug it, but an error happened:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -g D:\source\SDLearn\main.c -o D:\source\SDLearn\main.exe
D:\source\SDLearn\main.c:1:10: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "SDL2/SDL.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

And Intellisense detected SDL directory, it showed "SDL.h" in my coding tip.

I just used CMake with it, and CMakeLists.txt just like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(SDLearn VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/source/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
add_executable(SDLearn main.c)
```

Besides, I also added another config to `settings.json`

```
    "cmake.configureSettings": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "[vcpkg root]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      }
```

Now it looks like this:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "sdl.h": "c"
    },
    "cmake.configureSettings": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "[vcpkg root]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      }
}
```

But I don't what I should do.

Comment: Why use Vcpkg with MinGW? It's mostly targeted at Visual Studio (note, not VSC), and there are package managers that specialize on MinGW, such as [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

Comment: As for your error, VSC settings only affect the hints in the editor, not the actual compilation. You need to add `-I${vcpkgRoot}/x64-windows/include` to the compiler flags (and you might have to manually spell out the vcpkg location). This wouldn't have been necessary if you were using MSYS2.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for your comments, I just started using CMake with vscode.  But I found that Intellisense won't detect SDL directory when I use CMake, and the problem still exits... XD Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your question, `"SDL2/SDL.h"` should probably be `<SDL2/SDL.h>`. Both will work, but it's customary to use `<` `>` for libraries and system headers, as opposed to your own headers.

Comment: Can't help with CMake, sorry. I suggest editing your question and adding the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OK, I have corrected it and will try it again.